# httprequest.GetResponse() hang?

Tags: c#, .net

I meet a issue that is related to the following code , anyone know how to fix it?

code snippet

```
 using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Comment: what resource/page does the request go to? Hopefully it's rather small since you're loading everything into a string.

Comment: it is small , several K at most

Comment: Have you tried providing a different URI to the request? I could speculate that this could happen due to unclosed connections exhausting the system, but I suppose you've already checked that.

Answer (score 0):

Look into "[Aysncronous HttpWebResponse](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&biw=980&bih=700&q=asynchronous+HttpWebResponse&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)"'s

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=582